# JQuery -- What is the correct syntax for targeting a div by a "constructed" ID?

Tags: jquery, syntax, radio-button

I'm writing a function to hide a div and clear all of its radio buttons back to the unchecked state.

I target the div by piecing together its ID using a variable, like so:

```
$('#'+target).hide();
```

I'd like to clear all the radio buttons inside, but I don't know the right syntax.  The following doesn't work.  How can I fix it?

```
$('('#'+target) :radio').prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either append everything in the same selector or use find as a subselector like so:

`$('#'+target+' :radio').prop('checked', false);` or
`$('#'+target).find(':radio').prop('checked', false);`